# List from model Kotlin not neatly arranged

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner, mutablelist

I try to get list from mutable list and parse it to array become spinner array, here is my code;

```
fun getListLeague(context: Context): MutableList<League> {
        val league: MutableList<League> = mutableListOf()
        val leagueName = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.leagueName)
        val leagueId = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.leagueId)

        league.clear()

        for (i in leagueName.indices) {
            league.add(League(leagueName[i], leagueId[i]))
        }

        return league
    }
```

Then I call it in my spinner in fragment, here is the code;

```
private lateinit var leagues: List<League>

    leagues = getListLeague(requireContext())
    val spinAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, leagues)

    Log.e("LIST LEAGUE PREV", leagues.toString())
```

I try to see the list from Log above, and I expect the result is like below;

```
E/LIST LEAGUE PREV: English Premier League, English League Championship, Scottish Premier League, German Bundesliga, Italian Serie A, French Ligue 1, Spanish La Liga, so on :)
```

Then I try to run the app, but the log result is appear like below:

```
E/LIST LEAGUE PREV: [League(leagueName=English Premier League, leagueId=4328), League(leagueName=English League Championship, leagueId=4329), League(leagueName=Scottish Premier League, leagueId=4330), League(leagueName=German Bundesliga, leagueId=4331), League(leagueName=Italian Serie A, leagueId=4332), League(leagueName=French Ligue 1, leagueId=4334), League(leagueName=Spanish La Liga, leagueId=4335), League(leagueName=Greek Superleague Greece, leagueId=4336), League(leagueName=Dutch Eredivisie, leagueId=4337), League(leagueName=Belgian Jupiler League, leagueId=4338), League(leagueName=Turkish Super Lig, leagueId=4339), League(leagueName=Danish Superliga, leagueId=4340), League(leagueName=Portuguese Primeira Liga, leagueId=4344), League(leagueName=American Major League Soccer, leagueId=4346), League(leagueName=Swedish Allsvenskan, leagueId=4347), League(leagueName=Mexican Primera League, leagueId=4350), League(leagueName=Brazilian Brasileirao, leagueId=4351), League(leagueName=Ukrainian Premier League, leagueId=4354), League(leagueName=Russian Football Premier League, leagueId=4355), League(leagueName=Australian A-League, leagueId=4356), League(leagueName=Eliteserien, leagueId=4358), League(leagueName=Chinese Super League, leagueId=4359)]
```

The result is under my expectation, so where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting both leagueID and leagueName in your getListLeague

```
val leagueId = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.leagueId)

league.add(League(leagueName[i], leagueId[i]))
```

And you are returning both attributes,

```
return league
```

This is why you are getting leagueID in your Log.

Secondly, you are calling this

```
leagues = getListLeague(requireContext())
Log.e("LIST LEAGUE PREV", leagues.toString())
```

so you get your result as

```
League(leagueName=English Premier League
```

My suggestion is to understand what you're doing first before making changes to your codes.

Comment: so what shoud i do to fix it?? please help me :)

Comment: @HilmyFauzee: the answer to that surely is in this answer. If you do not understand a specific thing, say what that thing is. Remember also that people will not do your work for you - this platform is to help you learn to do it yourself.